# What is "same sort of thing" referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

In *L.A Confidential* (1997), the officer and Jack, working under the direction of Lieutenant Exley, teamed up to investigate the Night Owl murder. They used a list of vehicles provided by the DMV to aid their investigation:

> Jack: We go by this list, we got zero chance of making this collar. I got a guy who knows what's going on south of Jefferson. He can put us at fifty-fifty.
>
> Officer: Jack, what are you doing? **Same sort of thing** that got you in trouble last time.
>
> Exley: I'll take those odds.

The specific actions or behavior that got Jack into trouble in the past are not explicitly mentioned in the given conversation. The dialogue only hints at Jack's previous troubles without providing specific details.

What does this "same sort of thing" refer to?